# How can I set the datepicker's date value in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

How can I dynamically set the datepicker's date value in Bootstrap?

```
                });

        $('.datepicker').datepicker();
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({                
            date: $('#datetimepicker1 input').val(),
            format : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
        }).on('dp.change', function(ev){
            $('#datetimepicker1 input').val(ev.date)
        });

        // $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('hide');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```js
 $(".datepicker").datepicker("update", new Date());
```

Comment: You can see methods:  http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html

Comment: Requirements
Bootstrap 2.0.4+
jQuery 1.7.1+